# If $y=x^2$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$, which means if we increase $x$ by 1, $y$ would change by $2x$, but it actually follows $2x+1$, why?

Tags: derivatives

Say $x=5$, then $y=25$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = 10$.But $6^2-5^2 = 11$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $dy/dx$ is the *instantaneous* rate of change. It is how fast $y$ is changing when $x = 5$. When $x = 5.1$, it's different (and a little larger). When $x = 5.2$, it's still larger, and so on.

Comment: Because the derivative measures the limit of the difference, say, infinitesimal difference, not the real one. That is, $y(x+\varepsilon)\approx y(x)+\varepsilon \frac{dy}{dx}$ only as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. You can't just put $\varepsilon=1$.

Comment: Or for a more practical explanation than my first comment: You look at your speedometer and see it read 30 mph at some time. However, you're able to travel 60 miles in an hour. Why? Because you sped up.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is confusing the idea of $\frac{dy}{dx} $ with $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Remember that $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} =\frac{dy}{dx}$$

What you are doing is equating  $\frac{dy}{dx} $ with $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is wrong. It means that if you increase $x$ by $1$, then $y$ would change by $2x$ **along the tangent line**, not along the curve.

So, in your specific numerical example, you start at the point of tangency $(5,25)$ and move to the point $(5+1,25+2\cdot1) = (6,27)$. Both points lie on the tangent line to the curve at $(5,25)$. You have moved away from the curve by now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the graph of $y=x^2$ and $y=2x-1$, the line tangent to $x^2$ at $x=1$.

Graph from [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)
[image]

When you increment $x$ by $1$ and expect $y$ to grow by $2$, you are following this tangent line. But if you want to find the $y$ value of the curve when incrementing $x$, you must follow the curve itself.

**Remark:**

This method of following the tangent line can be used to find numerical solutions to differential equations when it's too hard to solve them analytically.

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial theorem, $(x+\epsilon)^2=x^2+2x\epsilon + \epsilon^2 = f(x)+\epsilon f'(x)+\epsilon^2$.  If $\epsilon$ is very small (at a minimum smaller than $1$, but ideally significantly smaller), then $\epsilon^2$ will be very very small (e.g., if $\epsilon=0.1, \epsilon^2=0.01$).  Therefore, for small values of $\epsilon$, $f(x+\epsilon)\approx f(x)+\epsilon f'(x)$.  However, this is just an approximation.  In a sense that can be made completely rigorous, this is the best linear approximation possible at $x$ (viewing the function as a function of $\epsilon$), but it is still only an approximation.  The error term, $\epsilon^2$ is very small when $\epsilon$ is small, but it is also very large when $\epsilon$ is large, so you only have a good approximation for small $\epsilon$.

All of this generalizes to other nice functions, of course, but for now, just remember that the average speed over a trip (the slope of a secant line) cannot be determined by knowing only the current speed ($f'(x)$) and the time of the trip ($\epsilon$).